# Relations between variables in thermodynamic potentials

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider the differential internal energy (for a single particle type), or the "fundamental relation":

$dU = TdS - PdV + \mu dN$

The "natural variables" are $S$, $V$, and $N$, meaning that they are held constant.

Now, what does this say about the non-natural variables $T$, $V$, and $\mu$?

For example, is temperature $T$ a function of the other non-natural variables (ie., $T=T(V,\mu)$) or is $T$ a function of the natural variables that it isn't multiplied by (ie., $T=T(V,N)$)?

Comment: "divide" both sides, for example, by $dV$ the you get $\left ( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right )_{S,N}  = -p$ implying that $p=p(S,V,N)$

Comment: Note though that of course you can introduce a new function $g$ such that $g(T, V, \mu) = p(S,V,N)$  where $T=T(S,V,N)$ so numerically $g=p$ but functionally those are different functions of their respective variables. It is unfortunate that in thermal physics the two are not distinguished explicitly by some clever notation thus leading to innumerable confusion.

Comment: Is there any such things natural variable or non-natural variables? What's the point to make this difference?

Comment: @user115350 yes, there is such a thing. A natural set of thermodynamic variables are the ones that can be controlled by the experimenter. For example, if $T,V$ are controllable then we use the Helmholtz free energy $F(T,V)$ based on $dF=-SdT-pdV$. If we control $T,p$ then we use the Gibbs free energy $G(T,p)$ via $dG=-SdT+Vdp$, etc. If we choose $S,V$ as independent variables then we assume that both$S$ and $V$ are under our control. It is difficult to control $S$ directly, $S=const$ implies an adiabatic process and we can change it via $dS =\delta Q/T$, i.e., calorimetry.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks though I would more be comfortable to see "independent variables" than "natural variable".